# In CakePHP, how to leave all prefixes?

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have a link that goes like this:

```
$this->Html->link('Welcome', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));
```

I suspect it doesn't work (Firefox says the redirect will never complete), so I did this:

```
$this->Html->link('Welcome', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add', 'my'=>false));
```

'my' is a prefix. I also have 'admin', 'ajax', and 'rss'. So now instead of pointing to /users/add or /my/users/add, the link points to /rss/users/add. The link is in a header, in a layout so I don't know which prefix it will be invoked from. I want to go to /users/add, that is, leave all prefixes altogether. How do I do that in CakePHP? I'm using 1.3 version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the prefix from `$this->params`, like this:

```
$this->Html->link('Welcome',
  array('controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'add',
        $this->params['prefix'] => false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
First, if Firefox says the redirect will never complete, then you have something wrong within the 'receiving' action (i.e. the add action) or with Routes configuration that is redirecting over and over again.

Second: I trust you configured your custom prefixes following [the Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/950/Prefix-Routing). But I also see that there can be a problem with the order of parameters. Place prefixes at the beginning, like this:

`$this->Html->link('Welcome', array('my' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));`

I say so because if I recall correctly, parameters after the 'action' parameter are treated as additional url parameters (i.e. /users/add/foo/bar:bla).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem was with Components for some reason. I added a custom component called Logic, and that broke things. I removed the component, things started working again.

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp 3, use something like this below

```
$this->Html->link('Welcome', array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'add', 
    'prefix' => false)
);
```